# Is it possible to make a pod stay in minikube without terminating and restarting after error?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to making a pod running MongoDB in minikube, I am working with my teammate, but we end up in different kinds of errors. The problem is that when the pod runs to an error which is related to MongoDB, the pod terminates and then restarts after a CrashLoopBackOff timeout. I'd like to log into the pod using "kubectl exec -it" and examine the files there, but there is no time for me to do so because the pod terminates upon error. Is it possible to config the pod using .yaml file so that the pod will stay there (since it is not a fatal error OS-wise)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace the `cmd` with a sleep command
2. SSH into the pod
3. Execute your real command manually, observe the effect.

Example YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: simple-spinner
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myapp-container
      image: busybox:1.28  # replace it with your image
      command:
      - '/bin/sh'
      - '-c'
      - |
        while true; do echo $(date); sleep 1; done
```